# What is the bounding function (Big-O) of the number of times the indicated line is run? (C)

Tags: c, runtime, big-o

I'm trying to grasp the concept of runtime and Im a bit confused on this problem. I know the runtime of the outer loop is O(n). I also know for values of n greater than 1000, the inner loop will run in constant time. However, for values of n < 1000, the inner loop appears to have a logarithmic runtime. So does this mean the Big O of the function would be O(n log n) since I'm supposed to assume worst case scenario?

```
for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  for(j = 1000/i; j > 0; j--) {
     arr[j]++;     <-------- THIS LINE
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation describes the behavior as n approaches infinity.
A=O(B) where A and B are functions of n, means that the limit of A/B when n approaches positive infinity is smaller than positive infinity.
So the cases under n=1000 don't affect Big O notation.

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic runtime of that code is **O(1)** i.e. no matter how large `n` is, there exists a constant that is `<=` than the number of times the line `arr[j]++;` is executed, and that constant happens to be rather small.

Proof:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int test(long long int n) {
   long long int ct = 0;
   long long int i, j;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       for (j = 1000/i; j > 0; j--) {
          ct ++;
       }
   }
   return ct;
}

int main(void) {
    long long int n;
    for (n = 1; n < 100000000; n *= 10) {
        printf("testing with n = %lld: ct = %lld\n", n, test(n));
    }
}
```

The output is

```
testing with n = 1: ct = 0
testing with n = 10: ct = 2827
testing with n = 100: ct = 5132
testing with n = 1000: ct = 7068
testing with n = 10000: ct = 7069
testing with n = 100000: ct = 7069
testing with n = 1000000: ct = 7069
testing with n = 10000000: ct = 7069
```

It is bounded above by the hard constant 7069, which is never exceeded, as when `n` exceeds 1000, the quotient will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any n > 1000 that the inner loop will never run at all - the starting value of j, when factoring in integer division, is zero. As a result, after n exceeds 1000, the number of times that the inner loop runs is completely independent of n - only the first 1000 iterations of the outer loop will have that inner statement execute.

Since in the long run the number of iterations of the inner loop is independent of n, in a big-O sense the indicated statement runs O(1) times.

However, provided that you keep n small, you will see a logarithmic growth in the number of times that loop runs. Notice that when i = 1 the loop runs 1000 times, when i = 2 it runs 1000/2 times, etc. Ignoring the effect of rounding down, after k iterations of the outer loop the inner loop will run

> 1000 + 1000/2 + 1000/3 + ...+ 1000/k
>
> = 1000(1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/k)
>
> = 1000H<sub>K</sub>

times, where H<sub>k</sub> is the kth [harmonic number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). The kth harmonic number is Θ(log k), so ignoring the effects of rounding down the number of loop iterations will grow logarithmically.

To summarize, in the short term the growth is logarithmic, but due to integer division the answer is O(1).